# Magento 2 : modules install but not showing in admin panel

Tags: magento2

Please stop me tearing what is left of my hair out.

Magento 2.2.4, two modules installed via composer. Cleared var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed, var/cache, pub/static, generated/.
Then run :

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Modules show up fine in the list that scrolls past. Modules also list as enabled in app/etc/config.php

Then run

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The modules show up in pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US and generated/code, but there is absolutely no sign of them in the admin panel itself.

What am I missing? They deploy fine on the dev site which is running the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just realised that I needed flush the PHP OpCache!

Comment: You can accept it as your answer Or you can simply update in your question that how you solved this. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

check in your db under **setup_module** table, that your module exist or not, if exists check your menu.xml file under [vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml

Comment: Both shown in setup_module table. One module creates its own menu item, the other piggybacks on an existing menu item.

Answer (score 0):

check this command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

after this `setup:upgrade` then

```
setup:static-content:deploy
```

if problem not solve then check this

```
bin/magento module:status
```

this show your module enable or disable status.after that your problem not solve then please comment i will futher serve you.